# 10/100mbit woes on small home network

Tags: networking

I've a little home network like this:

```
PC A         Switch     PC B
--------     ----      ------
|  A   |-----| S |-----|  B  |
--------     -----     -------
               |
            ------
            | M  | ---->Internet
            ------
            SDSL Modem
```

The switch `S` is a Jensen wireless router set to bridge, has 4 10/100 ethernet ports.
The modem has only a 10mbit interface.

Now I'm having trouble getting 100Mbit from A to B.

- If I set A and B to 100mbit, A gets intermittent connectivity to anything, ping times out 80% of the time.
- If I unplug the modem from the switch, A and B talks using 100mbit fine.
- If I unplug A, B talks to the switch fine using 100mbit (and no problems talking to the modem/internet)
- If I unplug B, A talks to the switch fine using 100mbit (and no problems talking to the modem/internet)
- If I set A to 10mbit, B to 100mbit, there are no problems.
- Have tested 2 different NICs in A, with same result.
- Can't change the nic in B, no expansion slots, have some integrated nvidia NIC (uses the focedeath driver on linux), A runs Win-7, Realtel 8169/8110

Where's could the real problem be? Would I gain anything buying a regular switch instead of using my wireless router in bridged mode?

Comment: what is the connection speed between the switch and the modem? just thinking that maybe the router/switch is using the lowest connected speed across the bridge.

Comment: Modem is 10 only, so modem to switch can be no more then 10.  You would expect computer->switch<-computer to be 100, with computer to switch to modem only dropping down to 10 when it needs to get out, over the modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out my Switch , `S` in the drawing, just couldn't handle this. I replaced it with a new netgear switch, and everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Jensen router has the proper drivers to work with win 7. Do a firmware update, then reset everything and you should be good to go. Realtel has also had driver issues with win 7. You may also need to update those drivers as well.